# Change range formula to include multiple if statements VBA

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement

Bonjour!

I am trying to fill some cells with If functions.
In excel this would look like this:

> =if(B11="Apple"; "nice";**if**(B11="Banana";"Also nice";"why?")

If I only use the first part of the if statement the code runs without problem

```
rng.formula = "=if(B11=""Apple"", ""Nice"", ""why?"")"
```

However, as soon as I add another if I get an

> Run Time Error '1004' Application defined or object-defined error

```
rng.Formula = "=if(B11=""Apple"",""Nice"",if(B11=""Banana"",""Also nice"",""why?"")"
```

How can I include several

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis: `rng.Formula = "=if(B11=""Apple"",""Nice"",if(B11=""Banana"",""Also nice"",""why?""))"`

Comment: when I tested your code, at first I also got that error. After next and next it is ok. I also don't know about it. Just restart your excel application.

Comment: Tip - when trying to put a formula into a cell via VBA, take that exact formula string and copy it into Excel directly - if it gives you an error when entering it manually, it will not work in VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a **parens**:

```
Sub dural()
    Set Rng = ActiveCell
    Rng.Formula = "=if(B11=""Apple"",""Nice"",if(B11=""Banana"",""Also nice"",""why?""))"
End Sub
```